# How can I change location for per-user and per-machine installations in Advanced Installer

Tags: java, advanced-installer

I want to add an per-user and per-machine installation type to my Advanced Installer project.
However default installation location is [AI_UserProgramFiles] which resolves to ProgramFiles in per-machine and LocalAppData in per-user installations.
This does not work, because my application downloads libs with Maven and saves temporary files, so I need non-administrative users to be able to modify contents of the per-machine location folder.

I thought ProgramData might be a good place, so I changed ApplicationFolder to [CommonAppDataFolder], but now the application is installed in ProgramData folder in both types (per-user and per-machine), which I do not think is right.
What folder should I use?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install in ProgramData only when the installation type is set to per-user, then you should leave the default installation location set [AI_UserProgramFiles]. Then you should just use a custom action that sets APPDIR property to [CommonAppDataFolder]. This custom action can be added as a published event on Next button.

[image]